# How do I treat the existing files(already committed) that I ignored later in git?

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

First the files are in the git repo and were committed thus not ignored. 
Then I ignore it in `gitignore`, and later those files are changed. 
They will show in `git status`.
In my project, those are some `pyc` files. 
I use

```
git rm <file> --cached
```

to remove them. 
I am wondering whether there is a better way to fix this.

Comment: Also, the `pyc` files are everywhere and I could not remove it using `git rm *.pyc --cached`, instead I have to remove it folder by folder. Any tip?

Comment: `git rm -r` should do the trick, the `-r` flag specifies recursive removal. See the manual [page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html) for more help on the flag.

Comment: Thank you @miqid , it worked. I've already tried it before, but with no luck. The reason is I didn't escape `*`. So `git rm -r \*.pyc --cached` could do the job. Nice one~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought it might also be worth mentioning that if you have more tracked files that you wish to ignore in the future, a nice way of dealing with this would be to add the relevant `.gitignore` entries, wipe the index and then re-add all files, like so:

```
git rm -r --cached .                // top-most directory
git add .
git commit -m "Updated .gitignore"
```

It is certainly much faster and less tedious than removing files one-by-one! :-)